# I get error when i use fgets instead of gets

Tags: c

This is a picture when I use fgets. (it does not work properly, insanely slow !!)

[image]

and This is a picture when it comes to gets. (works fine)

[image]

```
# define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct sNode {
    struct sNode* tNode;
    int G[20];
};

struct tNode {
    struct tNode* prev;
    struct tNode* next;
    int data;
    int used;
};

int convert_input(struct sNode** t_ArrayRef, char string[200])
{
    int j = 0, i = 0, temp = 0;
    int K[20];
    while (string[i] != '\0')
    {
        temp = 0;
        while (string[i] != ' ' && string[i] != '\0')
            temp = temp * 10 + (string[i++] - '0');
        if (string[i] == ' ')
        {
            i++;
        }

        (*t_ArrayRef)->G[j++] = temp;

    }

    return j - 1;
}

int main() {

int i;
char string[200];
char* str[5];

struct sNode* t = (struct sNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct sNode));

str[0] = string;


//fgets(str[0], sizeof(str[0]), stdin); // doesn't works !!!
gets(str[0]); // works !!!

int c = convert_input(&t, str[0]);

int num = t->G[0];
const int a = num;
struct tNode* tNod[6000];

for (i = 0; i<num; i++) {
    tNod[i] = (struct tNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct tNode));
}i = 0;

for (i = 1; i<num; i++) {
    tNod[i - 1]->data = i;
    tNod[i - 1]->used = 0;

    if (i != num - 1) {
        tNod[i - 1]->next = tNod[i];
    }
    else {
        tNod[i - 1]->next = tNod[i];
        tNod[i]->data = i + 1;
        tNod[i]->next = tNod[0];
    }
}i = 0;

struct tNode* current;

i = 1; int j = 0; int fCount = 0; int zCount = 0;
current = tNod[i - 1];
printf("<");
while (fCount == 0) {
    while (current->used == 1) {
        current = current->next;
        j++;
        if (j > num) {
            fCount = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    j = 0;
    if (i % t->G[1] == 0 && fCount == 0) {
        zCount++;
        if (zCount != t->G[0]) {
            printf("%d, ", current->data, i);
            current->used = 1;
        }
        else {
            printf("%d", current->data, i);
            current->used = 1;
        }
    }
    i++;
    current = current->next;
}
printf(">");
return 0;
```

}

Could anyone explain to me why I can't get it working using fgets ?

Comment: 1) `sizeof(str[0])` is `sizeof(char*)`, not buffer size.

Comment: 2) Since the result of `fgets` contains a newline, it is necessary to exclude newline. For example, use `strcspn` (`#include <string.h>`) after `fgets` as follows. E.g. `str[0][strcspn(str[0], "\n")]=0;`

Comment: the thing that BLUEPIXY mentioned is really helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use

```
fgets(str[0], sizeof(str[0]), stdin);
```

you do not pass the correct size: `sizeof(str[0])` is the size of a pointer to `char`, not the size of the 200-byte `char` array that you stored in it.

The compiler resolves this `sizeof` operator at compile time. It has no idea about the value that you put into element zero. In fact, it ignores zero altogether, replacing with `sizeof(*str)`.

Fix this problem by passing the proper size:

```
fgets(str[0], sizeof(string), stdin);
```

Comment: Note that there are two objects named `string` in the program. The `string` referenced in the `fgets` call is an array of 200 `char` elements. But the second parameter to the `convert_input()` function is also named `string`, and it's a pointer, not an array (a function parameter defined with array syntax is really an array, and the size is quietly ignored). It would be clearer to declare the function as `int convert_input(struct sNode** t_ArrayRef, char *string)` -- and it wouldn't hurt to pick a name other than `string`.